# How get Avro GenericRecord Size

Tags: java, bigdata, avro, parquet

i'm trying to buffer many Avro GenericRecords(256mo) in order to convert them to parquet file.

in order to do that i need a way(method or an external api) that allows me to get each GenericRecord size.

do you have any idea how i can do that ?

thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to use GenericRecord.toString().getBytes().length, but the size is off by quite a bit

Comment: any solution yet?